# DB2 WITH RETURN in even Simple Stored Procedure generates " Clauses not valid in same definition."

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, db2, websphere

Im at a loss right now because even on the most simple statement,

```
BEGIN 
        DECLARE rs1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR  
            select * from table1;
END
```

WITH RETURN is generating a

```
SQL Error [42613]: [SQL0628] Clauses not valid in same definition.
```

The Documentation https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=codes-listing-sql-messages says:

```
Clauses specified to define the attributes of a column, a sourced function, a procedure, a trigger, or an index are not valid. One of the following has occurred:

WITH RETURN is specified for a cursor in a compound (dynamic) statement.
```

How is this Select statement supposed to be called for a Cursor without being considered a dynamic statement?

Comment: Add your Db2 version and platform.

Comment: DB2 IBM i 7.3 (AS 400)

Comment: Do you really try to use `WITH RETURN` in a dynamic compound statement as you showed and not in a stored procedure definition?

Comment: Yes, the code is exactly as seen as above (minus the actual table names)

Answer (score 2):

See [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=statements-declare-cursor)

> WITH RETURN
> Specifies that the result table of the cursor is intended to be used as a procedure result set. If the DECLARE CURSOR statement is not
> contained within the source code for a **procedure**, the clause is
> ignored.